# Can we access Librato dashboard from AWS lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, librato

I am currently logging something into [Librato](https://www.librato.com/) metrics in my c# code as below:

```
// need to install librato4net nuget package
MetricsPublisher.Current.Increment("metricsName");
```

Now, I want to create a lambda function on Amazon Web service which will periodically do the same thing. But I am not able to figure out how to reference librato in the lambda function. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I assume you mean "post metrics from Lambda" and not "access dashboard from Lambda" correct?

Librato at it's core is designed for custom metrics. As long as you have access to the Interwebs you can POST values to our RESTful API. So there's always the option of hitting the API with a simple HTTP POST if you can deal with the additional overhead (direct synchronous call to API using a language binding or REST client) or if you want to make an async call you could call another Lambda that logs the metric and then takes care of POSTing to Librato.

Comment: Yes, I meant posting metrics from lambda. Basically I need to figure out a way to do the same thing (which I am doing in c#) in nodejs. I think I found a solution for that I just had to install the librato metrics package to be able to do it. Thanks.